# scale awesomefont5 icon to fill the box border

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below code create a node with a icon from awesomefont5 library but it's too small. I would like the icon scale to the border dimension.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{box/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm}}
  \node[box] (A) at (0,0) {\faHeadset};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `inner sep=0pt` and `\resizebox`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{box/.style={
        draw,
        inner sep=0pt,
        }}
\node[box] (A) at (0,0) {\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\faHeadset}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\rule{1pt}{1cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some variations to @pascal974 anwer:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{box/.style={
                %draw,
                inner sep=0pt,
        }}
        \node[box] (A) at (0,0) {\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\color{cyan}{\faHeadset}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{box/.style={
                inner sep=0pt,
        }}
        \node[box,cyan] (A) at (0,0) {\resizebox{1cm}{!}{\colorbox{gray}{\faHeadset}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{box/.style={
                %draw,
                inner sep=0pt,
        }}
        \node[box,red] (A) at (0,0) {\resizebox{1cm}{!}{{\faHeadset}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \rule{2pt}{1cm}
\end{document}
```

After verifications You can delete or comment tue line for dimensions controls (`\rule`...)-